# How do you use MySQL's source command within another file

Tags: mysql, sql, terminal

Im attempting to source a file 2019Dump.sql within another file solution2.sql.

Use a backup file 2019Dump.sql to load the pre 01 January 2020 contents of
relational tables LOCATED, SERVES and ORDERS into the database abc123.

I am running the solution2.sql through terminal using source solution2.sql.
when I run solution2.sql it is meant to source and run 2019Dump.sql.

I have tried 2 methods that (I have found and both error (42000)

source 2019Dump.sql;

mysql -u root -p abc123 < 2019Dump.sql;

Comment: MySQL is one product, SQL Server is another. They have few things in common.

Comment: sorry didn't mean to confuse anyone. Thank you

Comment: 42000 is a syntax error which typically explains what the problem is. What is the *actual* error message? Perhaps the syntax used by the source MySQL version isn't compatible with the target, eg MySQL 9 has different syntax than MySQL 5.7.x.

Comment: Dumps aren't backups either, they are scripts. That's why they are so big and so slow to make and restore. Trying to execute that script on a lower database version can easily fail. MySQL offers real backups only in the Enterprise edition.